# Como crear una opacidad

Tags: html5, css3, gulp-sass

Hola tengo una duda como poder seleccionar una imagen para darle opacidad ya que yo la agregue de la siguiente manera

anexo imagen y codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.no-webp .inicio {
    background-image: url(../../build/img/img1.jpg);
}

.webp .inicio {
    background-image: url(../../build/img/img1.jpg);
}
```

como verán anexe así la imagen pero quiero ver si puedo darle una opacidad para que no este tan fuerte el color de la imagen.
un cordial saludo y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar :before para tus elementos

```
.webp .inicio {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.webp .inicio:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  opacity: .4; 
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(../../build/img/img1.jpg);
}
```

Comment: no me funciona desaparece la imagen

Answer (score 0):

`.no-webp .inicio { opacity: 0.5;}`

la propiedad **opacity** puede ser desde **0.1** a **1**, siendo **1** el valor por default.